# como hacer que un tablix en reportviewer continue aun costado de la misma hoja antes de hacer el salto de pagina?

Tags: c#, reportviewer, visual-studio-2019

En un ***Tablix*** tengo elementos agrupados y despliega la información en forma vertical. Lo que quiero hacer es que antes de dar el salto de pagina, continúe aun lado en la misma hoja, así hasta llenar la hoja y después realizar el salto de pagina..... existe una forma de hacerlo??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en tiempo de ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon una imagen en tiempo de ejecución para ver cómo se ve tu reporte porque no te entiendo

Comment: Hola!!, La información se despliega en sentido vertical.. Quiero que al llegar al final de la hoja en vez de dar un salto de pagina, continúe aun costado y así sucesivamente hasta llenar la hoja, y entonces dar el salto de pagina para continuar.

Comment: Estas trabajando con entityframework?

Comment: No...por SQL genero un DataSet, que es el que utilizo para el reporte y para generar el reporte utilizo el reportviewer rdlc de VisualStudio 2019